# Overflowing width for number input inside bootstrap input group

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, firefox

To use an input addon in twitter bootstrap (a label before/after the input), the input should be added inside an `.input-group`. It works fine when using most input types, but not in the case of **number inputs** in **Firefox**. The input group overflows it's parent's width when parent is too narrow. This problem only seem to appear in Firefox.

[image: A couple examples comparing number and text inputs]

```css
.content {
  padding: 20px;
  width: 250px;
}
.form-group {
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="content">

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputAmount">Amount (in dollars)</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <div class="input-group-addon">$</div>
      <input class="form-control" id="exampleInputAmount" placeholder="Amount" type="number">
      <div class="input-group-addon">.00</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputAmount">Amount (in dollars)</label>
    <input class="form-control" id="exampleInputAmount" placeholder="Amount" type="number">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputAmount">Amount (in dollars)</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <input class="form-control" id="exampleInputAmount" placeholder="Amount" type="text">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputAmount">Amount (in dollars)</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <div class="input-group-addon">$</div>
      <input class="form-control" id="exampleInputAmount" placeholder="Amount" type="text">
      <div class="input-group-addon">.00</div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that this problem only exists in Firefox Developer Edition, so it will probably be fixed in future versions.